# New to RShiny. Is there a way to further restrict a graph's x-axis using a second input?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to RShiny, and I'm looking at the tutorials on the site, specifically this one: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html

We see the input box on the left, where users can choose the region, and that region's data is displayed in the histogram.

Would there be a way to add another layer of input? For instance, on this histogram could we add another input box choosing the year (1951, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961) so that only one data point is displayed? (This would obviously not be ideal for a simple dataset like this one, but if there was additional information about something like "area code" we would be able to see the data broken up on an additional level.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic extension of that example with a second input, allowing you to compare years in one region, compare regions in one year, or (in a very convoluted way) look at a specific year-region pair. I have more or less just passed one more argument to `sidebarPanel` specifying a second input `year` and modified the `renderPlot` expression to condition on both `year` and `region`.

```r
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(    
  titlePanel("Telephones by year and region"),
  sidebarLayout(      
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("year", "Year:", choices = c("", rownames(WorldPhones))),
      selectInput("region", "Region:", choices = c(colnames(WorldPhones), "")),
      hr(),
      helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("phonePlot")  
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
    ylab <- "number of telephones"
    if (nzchar(input$region)) {
      height <- 1000 * WorldPhones[, input$region]
      if (nzchar(input$year)) {
        height <- height[input$year]
      }
      barplot(height = height, main = input$region, ylab = ylab, xlab = "year")
    } else {
      if (nzchar(input$year)) {
        height <- 1000 * WorldPhones[input$year, ]
        barplot(height = height, main = input$year, ylab = ylab, xlab = "region")
      } else {
        validate("At least one of year and region must be specified.")
      }
    }
  })
}

app <- shinyApp(ui, server)
runApp(app)
```

More generally, it may help you to review [this book](https://mastering-shiny.org/) before/while digging into the example database.